# weakly harmonic implies derivative is too

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I have the following problem

Let $R> 0$, $B(0,R) \subset \mathbb R^n$ a ball with radius $R$ and $w \in H^1(B(0,R))$ weakly harmonic, that is $\forall \varphi \in C^\infty_c(B(0,R)) \, :$ $$\int_{B(0,R)} \nabla w \, \nabla \varphi \, \mathrm d x = 0$$

**How can I show, that $\partial_i w$ is also weakly harmonic on $B(0,R)$?**

I know that for all test functions there holds $\int_{B(0,R)} \nabla w \, \partial_i \nabla \varphi \, \mathrm d x = 0$, but that doesn't imply $\int_{B(0,R)} \nabla \partial_i w \,  \nabla \varphi \, \mathrm d x = 0$ for all $\varphi$.

My problem is to show that the derivative exists, although I don't know if $w \in H^2$.

Comment: Write weak harmonicity as $$\int_{B(0,R)} w \Delta \varphi\,dx = 0$$ for all test functions.

Comment: i agree, then it works. but how is this even 'weaker' sense of harmonicity equivalent to the 'stronger' harmonicity of my definition? here the function doesnt even have to be in $H^1$

Comment: In fact, a harmonic distribution is real-analytic (more precisely, a harmonic distribution is given by $\varphi \mapsto \int h(x)\varphi(x)\,dx$ where $h$ is a harmonic function in the classical sense). However, I don't think that $w \in H^1$ harmonic implies that $\partial_i w \in H^1$, the second derivatives of $w$ can grow too fast at some boundary points.

Comment: i agree, i also don't see why this should work, i guess im missing out something somewhere else

Comment: Well, we're using functions with compact support, so we only need $H^k_{\text{loc}}$, and since after possibly redefining $w$ on a set of measure $0$ we have $w\in C^{\infty}$, we have that.